# Non intrusive notification without audio?

Tags: c#, .net

i have a C# app that registers a protocol. When you click BLAH://djfhgjfdghjkd in a browser it launches my app. However you can click multiple links and each link is a note added into the app.

How can i inform the user that he did fully click the link? Right now i have a console app showing up for 1sec (basically pops up and goes away as fast as possible) which felt better then a hidden console since you are unsure if it went through. The 1 second takes a lot of time when you are trying to rapidly click many notes/links and the console gets in the way. What can i do that is noticeable?

I'm thinking have a box that comes up (and is semi transparent) but the click passes through it. Maybe there is a better way? Also i wouldnt know where to start with transparent windows or pass through clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at putting an icon in the SysTray, combined with balloon tips, that's the Windows way I think. Especially since it's even been renamed to the Notification Area.

Look at the [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) Class.

Comment: Good enough answer. I am also considering using growl (for windows)